# Should all business logic be implemented in DolphinDB scripts or in DolphinDB C++ API, which is faster and why?

Tags: c++, plugins, query-optimization, dolphindb

I'm currently using DolphinDB for data processing and considering using C++ or DolphinDB dos scripts to improve performance. Specifically, I want to compare the performance of these two methods:

(1) Method 1: First use DolphinDB C++ API to import data, and then all business logic is written in DolphinDB scripts.

(2) Methods 2: Use DolphinDB C++ API to import data and implement basicness logics.

Has anyone done this kind of comparison? If so, can you share some experiences and best practices? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 is more recommended:

(1) DolphinDB script is as efficient as C++ in implementing business logic, although it comes with parsing overhead. In addition, DolphinDB offers a great number of built-in functions that enable optimal performance and clean code.

(2) DolphinDB script is simple to write and read, so it is easy to modify or reuse the business logic as required.

(3) The plugin and server share one process, which can save the overhead of data transfer.